# Using Index to create a dynamic range issue with non-blank blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

So I am having issues defining a dynamic table range using the index function, I think the problem is arising because the table I am attempting to create a dynamic range for has cells inside that are part of an array but I am not sure.

I am currently using this function which works in the fact that it names H17 as the bottom right cell with text in the range;

```
=INDEX(C2:H1000,(COUNTA(C2:C103)-COUNTBLANK(C2:C103)),COUNTA(C2:H2))
```

(Also worth noting that when I change the above function to this it ceases to work for some reason? it throws up a #VALUE error?

```
=INDEX(C2:H1000,(COUNTA(C2:C1000)-COUNTBLANK(C2:C1000)),COUNTA(C2:H2))
```

When I place the top left cell in beside like this into the name manager I cannot seem to get it to function the same way as I have another table to function inside of my VBA code, which just pastes the table into a word document?

```
=$C$2:INDEX(C2:H1000,(COUNTA(C2:C103)-COUNTBLANK(C2:C103)),COUNTA(C2:H2))
```

I also used the CountA function to try to count just the cells with the numbers in column C but that did not work using the function below:

```
=INDEX(C2:H1000,(COUNTA(C2:C1000)),COUNTA(C2:H2))
```

Code used to paste into word:

```
Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(7).Range("SummaryTableTest")
'& ThisWorkbook.Sheets(7).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(7).Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Value
'.Copy

'Copy the range
tbl.Copy

'Pause the Excel app for one second

Application.Wait Now() + #12:00:01 AM#

'Paste the object (Ensuring that it will be paste from the correct clip board i.e. Excel)
With WordApp.Selection
WordDoc.Bookmarks("SummaryTable").Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, _
WordFormatting:=True, _
RTF:=False
End With
```

The spreadsheet looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you just trying to [get the last populated row of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631926/lastrow-and-excel-table)?

Comment: yes I am, it works for other ranges, it is just this range that I am having an issue with.

Comment: Just use the approach in that linked question.

Comment: I have used an OFFSET function to solve the issue, but it does not work for INDEX for some reason