# not according to the desired result of the vba code

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

If you look at the sheet "test" results in column T there is an error 2042 and cause the row table to be more, what solution only slight modifications but without changing the structure of the code.

Thanks
jack

```
Sub test()
  Dim Z, U&
With Sheets("test").Range("t2:t" & Sheets("test").Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
       .Formula = "=LOOKUP([@Date]+0.5,Table2[Date]/(Table2[ITEM NO]=[@[ITEM NO]]),Table2[PRICE])"
        Z = .Value
        For U = 1 To UBound(Z):  Z(U, 1) = CStr(Z(U, 1)):  Next
       .Value2 = Z
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: SHEET TEST]
[image: SHEET SOURCe]
[image: SHEET TEST INPUT]

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631926/lastrow-and-excel-table) perhaps for how to find the last row in a table.

Comment: @BigBen , Thanks for your reply, can you create a solution from my code and answer in return for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Determine Last Row When Rows Are Blank (But Not Empty)

```vb
Dim lRow As Long
With Worksheets("test").Range("H2")
    Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count _
        - .Row + 1).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    lRow = lCell.Row
End With
    
With Worksheets("test").Range("T2:T" & lRow)
' continue...

End With
```

If you don't care about accuracy and testing you can use:

```
With Worksheets("test").Range("T2:T" & Worksheets("test").Columns("H").Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious).Row)
' continue...

End With
```