# How to grab last row of first table of multiple in 1 sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, vba7, vba6

Hi I am trying to grab the last row in a table. Thing is, there's multiple tables in one sheet. Picture of excel file format for reference:

[image]

Usually I know I can like set a variable to refer to the last row via

`lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

But in this case, with that line I end up grabbing the last row of the VERY LAST table way down below. (like row 90)

Is there any way I can grab the last row of the first table? (In this case it'd be row 16)

Comment: Consider turning them into actual tables (Ctrl+T). Then you could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631926/lastrow-and-excel-table). Otherwise, you could loop and consider the cell formatting. If the first column is entirely populated with values, you could use `.End(xlDown)`.

Comment: Presumably these tables are not all blank?  Maybe find the first value on the sheet and then from that cell use `CurrentRegion`.  Assuming your tables contain no fully-empty rows or columns

Answer (score 0):

its hard to tell exactly what you need based on the example tables being blank. But you could try this, assuming each cell in column B of the first table is going to contain data / not be blank:

```
Sub Select_LastRow()

LastRowOfTable1 = Range("B3:B" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row - 1

Range("B" & LastRowOfTable1).Select

End Sub
```